# Using selenium to parse a class from browser

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape a google webpage for the title inside a td, this is the code I have got so far but I am missing something.

```
from selenium import webdriver

case_url = "http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3Acalm&ei=7DIoVcKZNo2ZjALz8YCYCw"


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(case_url)

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ctsymbol")

print(elem[1])

assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

driver.close()
```

### #

the class as seen on the browser is as follow:

IBA

Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are eleven elements with this class.
The method you're using, `find_element_by_class_name`, only returns one element. So with `elem[1]` you're asking for an element in a list, that's not actually a list.

If you want to have a list of all elements with this class, use `find_elements_by_class_name` - see http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html for the difference.